# stacking list items - at least one vector required

Tags: r, list, stack

I have a list as follows:

```
alist <- list(number1 = structure("something", .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), number2 = structure("something", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L)))
```

If I want to stack this list:

```
stack(alist)
```

It says: `Error in stack.default(test) : at least one vector element is required`

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```r
stack(unlist(alist))
```